# Maven build war package, replace properties in context directory under WEB-INF

Tags: maven, replace, properties, resources, pom.xml

I have a Maven project which directory like this -

```
MyProjectName
  > src/main/java
  > src/main/resources
     > test.properties
  > src
     > main
        > webapp
           > WEB-INF
              > context
                 > project.properties
  > pom.xml
```

I want to replace content in project.properties in context directory.
Both test.properties and project.properties is -

```
myprop2 = ${foo.bar}
```

pom.xml like this -

```
<project xmlns=...> 
  <dependencies>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>env-dev</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
              <name>env</name>
              <value>dev</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <foo.bar>othervalue</foo.bar>
        </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

In this way, when I run

```
mvn process-resources -Denv=dev
```

test.properties can be replaced as

```
myprop2 = othervalue
```

But, my question is, I don't know how to specific the file in context foler, I've tried

```
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/context  //1
WEB-INF/context                  //2

<configuration>                  //3
  <webResources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/context</directory>
    </resource>
  </webResources>
</configuration>
```

But it doesn't work, I want to replace content in project.properties just like test.properties. 
Anyone can help, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The maven war plugin allows you to add resource folders. see "webResources": http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html

I think that should simplify a few things.